# Spring Boot: Not able to connect to MySQL through STS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, sts

I want to connect to a MySQL DB through STS, but am getting this error:

```
[2m2023-03-13T08:40:09.974+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9720[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m root - Starting...
[2m2023-03-13T08:40:11.259+05:30[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m9720[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m root - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
```

Here are my `application.properties` and POM files. I have changed the database configuration code many times but it is not working.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/learn
spring.datasource.name=root
spring.datasource.password=2071
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect;
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.jpa.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootjpaexample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bootjpaexample</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.30</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using old dialect(MySQL57Dialect) with mysql 8.0.30 driver. I assume you are using mysql 8 server and that is generating the error. With latest spring boot 3 hibernate goes to version 6 and the dialect configuration changed.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

You can find all working code [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-mysql)

Comment: I went through the given url but I did not found any thing which I can fix issue of my program. Please help on this.

Comment: did you try the properties like in the answer ? more specifically delete  or comment *spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect* and start your project and share what error do you get.

Comment: Now I tried . It is working for me. Thanks a love  :) from side.